# Facebook Like button shares root URL instead of page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I've used the Facebook Like button (iframe version) correctly in the past but for some reason it's not working for me this time. I'm sharing a webpage like http://sub.domain.com/default.aspx?foo=bar. When I view the source HTML the URL shared in the iframe correctly displays http://sub.domain.com/default.aspx?foo=bar. When I check the OG meta URL property it's http://sub.domain.com/default.aspx?foo=bar (so far so good). When I click Like, it shares http://sub.domain.com.

Has anyone else had this issue. Like I said I've used this before. I can't figure out why the others work out of the box and this one isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a **<link rel="canonical" />** tag that specifies them as the same page?

Just an educated guess - never seen the canonical links affect Open Graph Protocol sharing before.

Comment: <meta property="og:url" ... /> tag will also do it.  I haven't tried but would guess the answer here is appending the "foo" get parameter to both these tags (assuming they're set, and assuming that they both currently reference the page sans params).

Answer (score 1):

Just add following two lines inside your `<Head>` Tag, you should be able to resolve the issue.

```
<link href="http://sub.domain.com/default.aspx?foo=bar" rel="canonical">
<meta content="http://sub.domain.com/default.aspx?foo=bar" property="og:url">
```

Here I just hard coded the url, but while you implement it, make sure that the url of each page is dynamic. You can use $SERVER variables to generate the urls of corresponding pages.

Feel free to contact if you need any support!

Answer (score 0):

Are these like buttons on the homepage? The default code likes the URL of the page the icon is on. This can be a problem when placing like buttons for child pages on a parent page.

Answer (score 0):

From Facebook Docs:

> The og:title links to og:url and the
>   og:site_name is rendered pointing to
>   your site's domain automatically.

"your sites domain" is the site_url, AFAIK there is no way to change this. see 
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint
and http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ (the part about meta tags)